# How can I get a 56k modem as a server using DSL?

Tags: networking, modem

I want to run an old school BBS system using a modem, and accessible to 33.6 and 56k users

I know there are technical differences with modems that go over POTS PSTN networks and that regular modems work up to 33.6 k and a DSL or fractional T1 is needed for 56k downloads over analog modems.

Can anyone educate me how to upgrade a 33.6 modem into one that supports 56k line?

Comment: “…and a DSL or fractional T1 is needed for 56k downloads over analog modems.” I have no idea what any of this means. If you want a dial in BSS it’s just a phone line. You just hook the modem up to the phone line and let people dial in. DSL or fractional T1 have nothing to do with anything.

Comment: Agree with @Giacomo1968 .. this makes no sense to me.  Please make it make sense.

Comment: Just so we are all clear on this: A dial-up modem just uses a standard dial-up line. Meaning a POTS line. Nothing fancy. Hook your modem up to the phone line and that is that. Modem speeds for POTS service can handle up to 56k but 33k was used as well. All data is handled via acoustic modem technology. A DSL line uses digital signaling on the higher frequencies of a POTS line to send data, but has nothing to do with POTS modems. And a T1 is a special kind of digital connection line that you need to get specially installed. So knowing that, utterly nothing you are asking makes sense. Sorry.

Comment: @Glacomo1968 I'll post an answer shortly (I need to see if I can recall/re-find the equipment) but , a 56k line required special equipment on the ISP end to get speeds in excess of 56k and typically used T1 connections at the ISP end.

Comment: @davidgo I don’t think you should post an answer because this question makes no sense. I have definitely used all kinds of modems up to 56k on a POTS without any special equipment. The only thing needed was for both modems to communicate in the same [56k protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem#Early_56k_dial-up_products): Either X2 in early USRobotics modems or V.90/V.92 which was the more standardized protocols. Either wait if the core of question is “I want to run an old school BBS system using a modem…” then the rest makes utterly no sense: DSL and T1 has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Anyway, if the original poster just mixed up jargon, then the only way to get 33.6k modem to support 56k is to just get a 56k modem and let people connect at whatever speed they can: 56k or lower. Nothing special here. It’s that simple.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Yes, you used a 56k modem on a POTS line, but the aprt you are missing is **to get this to work above 33.6k the ISP/BBS provider side needed to use specialist hardware - not 56k modems** (Trust me, I'd be a lot richer if this were not the case. I ran an ISP and had to make that jump)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - If it were as simple as getting a 56k modem on the ISP side, why were portmasters neccessary even for small providers if they wanted speeds above 56k.  Please trust that I know **exactly** what I am talking about.  Please read -  
Part 2: How 56k Modems Get 56k Speedsat http://www.99main.com/support/how56kworks.shtml

Comment: @davidgo I have no doubt you have knowledge, but this question is very simple: The original poster should just get a 56k modem and that’s that. No DSL, T1 or ISDN involved. And yes, speeds will most likely be 48k down and 40k up, but that is splitting hairs. This is someone looking to do something simple from a hobbies perspective; not an ISP who is looking to get the cleanest connections to be competitive in the once lucrative local dial-up ISP market. “…even for small providers if they wanted speeds above 56k.” See what I just wrote… Nuff said. This is not a history question. This is basic.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - YOU CAN NOT get speeds above 33.6k off a connection with 2 analog modems on it.   That was the point of my answer.  The mention of T1's also implies that the OP has some knowledge of this, and wanted to exceed 33.6k.

Comment: @davidgo Fair enough. I still contend this is a hobby user question and thus what is recommended is overkill.

Comment: @giacomo1968 On this we are agreed!

Comment: This is for a class I want to teach online, and it seems it’s needed given the activity. That or I need to ask questions to validate my questions as a Fractional T1 or DSL as a pre requisite post as TI 99 4A technology exposure has given me a lot of insight

Answer (score 1):

I think you mispoke when you said "DSL" - you likey meant "ISDN", and people without specific archaic knowledge likely misunderstand.  (I happen to have run an ISP in the 90's.  As this was 20+ years ago I might get some detailed detail wrong, but I'm fairly sure of the overall picture)

**The key thing is that to get download speeds above 33.6k, the ISP side had to be digital and had to use special equipment which provided a digital equivalent of banks of modems - it could not be done with regular analog modems**  (Also, getting 56k was pretty near impossible, although speeds in excess of 40k were common)

Both Basic Rate ISDN and (Primary Rate) T1's [ In New Zealand we used E1's - same idea, but 30 as opposed to 24 64 channels max ] provide(d) 64k digital channels which could be interfaced with POTS lines using specialist hardware.   There were a few manufacturers, but the only one I can find, and the one I recall using was the [Lucent Portmaster](http://www.portmasters.com/).   In order to get 56k working you would somehow need to get an ISP to provision a T1 or fractional T1 and then find and configure a working Portmaster on it - to be frank,its likely not worth doing even if you can find working hardware - you can use 56k modems in 33.6k mode on either end, or, if you need greater speed use some kind of emulator.

Comment: What this answer seems to describe sounds like an alternative to renting a plethora of POTS lines, installing a modem on each line, and then connecting each modem to a serial port of the ISP's computer/server.  Beyond some number of lines, modems and serial ports this scheme becomes unwieldy, and replacing that with a single xDSL or T1 ("T1 service" is usually implemented using xDSL) connection from the central office to the ISP premises, with the CO responsible for the modems, becomes more practical.  For just one or few incoming lines, the OP does not have to go this elaborate route.

Comment: @sawdust - If they want to exceed 33.6k they do.  You can't get more then 33.6k out of a pair of analog modems - even under ideal conditions.  One side needs to be digital.  (Making the jump from 33.6k to 56k support was a big commitment - I was already using 56k modems in my fledgling ISP at the time!)